# how do I pass outputtext to other form

Tags: jsf

as simple as this. But the outputtext is not passed to another function or form. inputtext of course works but looks ugly.

What should I subsititute outputtext with?

```
<h:form>
<h:outputtext value="xx" />

<h:commandButton action="#{serviceTest.function() }" value="test"
                </h:commandButton>

</h:form>
```

Real world example

```
<p:column id="average" sortBy="#{resultClub.stringAverage}">
                    <f:facet name="header">Snitt</f:facet>
                    <h:outputText id="testing" value="#{resultClub.stringAverage}" />
                    <h:inputHidden id="hiddenAvg" value="#{resultClub.stringAverage}" />
                </p:column>         

javax.faces.component.UpdateModelException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /hcp/showAverages.xhtml @96,74 value="#{resultClub.stringAverage}": Property 'stringAverage' not writable on type com.jk.hcp.ResultClub
    javax.faces.component.UIInput.updateModel(UIInput.java:867)
    javax.faces.component.UIInput.processUpdates(UIInput.java:749)
    org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.process(UIData.java:328)
```

Comment: Is adding a setter for `stringAverage` an option? B/c that will make the exception go away and you can use the `inputHidden` approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you described the problem to me, I figure it out for you...
You can do this by using javascript

**Outputtext:**

```
<h:outputText id="text1" value="xx" />
```

**Button:**

```
<h:commandButton value="click me"
    action="#{serviceTest.function()}" value="test"
    onclick="submitFieldValue()" >
</h:commandButton>
```

**XHTML:**
This will set the myfield instance variable in your controller. It basically will generate a java script function at compile time which will be able to call the controller.

```
<a4j:jsFunction name="setTheValue">
    <a4j:actionparam name="param" assignTo="#{serviceTest.myfield}"/>
</a4j:jsFunction>
```

**JavaScript:**
This will call `setTheValue` with the outputtext value

```
function submitFieldValue(){
var x = document.getElementById("text1").value;
setTheValue(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the "xx" value submitted after clicking on the commandButton, you can either use hidden field for it

```
<h:inputHidden value="some text" />
```

or you can use

```
<h:inputText readonly="true" />
```

which will render the text in an input text that user cannot change (it may look like the outputText), but its value will be submitted after clicking the button.

Comment: inputText looks really bad. and inputHidden give me an error.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is that you want to view some data in the outputtext after the button is pressed, right?
**Please if I got it wrong, tell me to delete the answer!**

Is this case you need to make the button renders the outputfield upon clicked:

Outputtext:

```
<h:outputText id="text1" value="#{serviceTest.text1Value}" />
```

Button:

```
<a4j:commandButton value="click me"
    action="#{serviceTest.function() }" value="test"
    render="text1" >
</a4j:commandButton>
```

As you can see I used `a4j:commandButton` which will enable me to render any element on the page by id upon click.

Comment: I want outputtext be able to send data to another form on submit. Just like it would if it was an inputtext field.

Comment: @user2130951 Okay, please follow my new answer?